# Access NGINX container in a different network on VM from host machine

Tags: docker, nginx

I have created three networks A, B and C using docker on a ubuntu VM, each network contained the three containers 2 busybox and 1 nginx. Each nginx container in different network i have port-forwarded on `80` `81` and `82` respectively using below commands:

```
sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 82:82 --network C --name web3 nginx

sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 81:81 --network B --name web2 nginx

sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 80:80 --network A --name web1 nginx
```

but when i tried to access the container from my host machine providing the ip address of my vm along with port e.g. `https://192.168.18.240:82` it does not give access to that container in different network. While giving the only IP address with port 80 am able to access the nginx but not on port `82` and `81`. I have cleared the cache and clear the browsing history but all in vain.

Comment: You're telling the (VM) host port 82 to forward to container port 82, but Nginx isn't listening there, it's on port 80 instead.  Use `-p 82:80`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the docker nginx containers listen on port 80. You are mapping B and C to the wrong container port.

```
sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 82:**80** --network C --name web3 nginx

sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 81:**80** --network B --name web2 nginx

sudo docker run -itd --rm -p 80:80 --network A --name web1 nginx
```